# Error: Configuration property "mongoURI" is not defined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I try to start a project but when I try to connect the mongo with the server I encounter an error that shows that the connection is not working because it can not find the folder where the connection string.

my db file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const config = require('config');
const db = config.get('mongoURI')


const connectDB = async () => {

try{
    await mongoose.connect(db);
    console.log('MongoDB connected..');
}catch(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1)
}
}

module.exports = connectDB;
```

my defualt.json:

```
{
 "mongoURI": "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@devconector- 
 zfloj.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
}
```

the error:
     WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:C:\Users\Yair 
     Azaria\Desktop\תכנות\node.js\DevConnector\config
     WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the 
     environment.
     C:\Users\Yair 
     Azaria\Desktop\node.js\DevConnector\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:203
     throw new Error('Configuration property "' + property + '" is not defined');
     ^

```
Error: Configuration property "mongoURI" is not defined at Config.get(C:\Users\YairAzaria\Desktop\תכנות\node.js\DevConnector\node_modules\config\lib\config.js:203:1)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\YairAzaria\Desktop\תכנות\node.js\DevConnector\config\db.js:3:19)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(C:\Users\YairAzaria\Desktop\תכנות\node.js\DevConnector\server.js:2:19)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
```

Comment: Is your mongoURI defined in the config, I mean  have you checked in the config whether it is defined or not and exported also? i believe it is an issue of mismatching of variable names. Please check.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to have a `config` folder on the root level of your project and a `default.json` file in that `config` folder.

In the `default.json` file, have your `mongoURI` value set up. And with that you should be able to have a value for `mongoURI` when you access it in your program (that you are doing now as shown in your code).

```
$ npm install config
$ mkdir config
$ vi config/default.json
{
  "mongoURI": ""mongodb://userID:password@mongoBox:27001/myMongoDB"
}
```

look in this link for more information https://www.npmjs.com/package/config

Comment: I did everything you said and it still does not work, Same error :(

Comment: I don't know what `I did everything` means but if you dont have to use `config` module...remove it and connect to the Mongo using directly (by hardcoding the `mongoURI` value instead of reading it from somewhere.

Comment: I deleted the config module and connected directly, now it works, Thank you very much :)

Comment: good to hear. Now that you solved this problem, think about PRODUCTION. You will have to read that value from your config file somehow (it does not have to be `config` module ). But I am glad to hear that you are making progress

Answer (score 1):

So the issue is that you did not properly spell "default", you spelt it as "defualt.json" instead of "default.json"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to get the dbURI from config.json file which does not exist in the folder. In your case you have named it as default.json so just replace the file name in the import section of your db.js and it would work fine. As shown below

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const defualt = require('defualt');
const db = defualt.mongoURI; 

const connectDB = async () => {

try{
    await mongoose.connect(db);
    console.log('MongoDB connected..');
}catch(err){
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exit(1)
}
}
```

Let me know the results!

Comment: no the OP is not trying to get `mongoURI` from `config.json`.  Here `config.json` is a `npm module`.

Comment: Thank you sunny.config is a npm module

Answer (score 0):

You have created config folder inside "src" folder. kindly move the config folder one directory out/up.

Comment: one of the answers from 2019 for the OP seems to already say effectively this .. Perhaps you can edit it to clarify the issue / add your suggestion (and then delete this answer).