# How do I solve Configuration property "jwt" and "DB" is not defined error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, config, web-deployment

I am trying to push my web application (MERN stack) to Heroku but I keep getting this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39Yz1.png)

What I have tried
in index.js

```
if (!config.get("jwtPrivateKey")) {
throw new Error('FATAL ERROR!!: jwtPrivateKey is not defined')
}

console.log(config.get("DB"))
console.log(config.get("jwtPrivateKey"))
```

This is their value when i log them

[the logs image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0nQO.png)

at the config folder there are two files default.json and custom-environment-variables.json
default.json

```
{
"jwtPrivateKey" : "",
"requiresAuth": false,
"DB":"mongodb+srv://****/test"
}
```

custom-environment-variables.json

```
{
"jwtPrivateKey" : "RhinoJohn_jwtPrivateKey",
"DB": "Rhinojohn_DB"
}
```

When i run heroku config here are the variables
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGPKm.png)

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298024/keep-getting-error-configuration-property-vidly-jwtprivatekey-is-not-defined) question but none of the answers solves my problem.
How do i solve  Configuration property "jwtPrivateKey" is not defined?? I'm out of options

Comment: what is the import statement for "config"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use environment variables instead of files as heroku supports them just fine and use them as

```
process.env.VARIABLE_NAME
```

Beacsue you are using react inside the .env file you will need to store them as

```
#.env file
REACT_APP_SECRET_NAME=secretvalue
```

meaning that is has to start with `REACT_APP_`

don't forget to add it inside the gitignore file if you're using git.

Comment: I really needed to use config files, plus i really think that the error is on the Heroku side, maybe there is a command that i haven't run yet

Comment: While using the environment variable I am still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should add the secrets as configVars in heroku via your dashboard. Navigate to the settings page first once in the app.
[image]

Select settings and look for this
[image]

once you reveal them you can add the same values from your config files, the keys and values should match 100% to what you have in your keys.config file or whatever file your storing the secrets in.

This is how i hav always done it to avoid posting config files on public repos

Comment: I already have set config variables